# Being told my code has too many "if" statements

Tags: python

```
def inbetween(numero):
    if 100 < numero < 1000:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

or

```
def inbetween(numero):
    if numero in range(100,1000):
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

The code itself works to find whether on not values are within 100-1000, yet i'm being told that my code has too many "ifs" and I really can't find a way to reduce them. (First stack overflow question btw)

Comment: Told by whom? In the first case, it's true you don't need a conditional at all: `return 100 < numero < 1000`. I see northing wrong with the second function.

Comment: Ask whoever told you that you have too many ifs, not random people on the internet.

Comment: You can replace the `if` *statement* with a conditional expression in the second: `print("yes" if numero in range(100, 1000) else "no")`, but that's little more than a matter of preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to return True or False, you can actually return the conditional which evaluates to True or False:

```
def inbetween(numero):
    return 100 < numero < 1000
```

Which will return the boolean value.

Answer (score 6):

A code of this form:

```
if <bool>:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Would usually be simplified to this form:

```
return <bool>
```